# check if record exists in javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a web app which passes delimited fields to another web page. It works fine! But... I want to list the fields (Name) that don't exist in the javascript object. How can this be accomplished?

JS object:

```
var members = [ { "Class": "E", "Rating": "1000", "ID": "16720664", "Name": "Adeyemon, Murie", "Expires": "1000.10.10" }, 
  { "Class": "B", "Rating": "1735", "ID": "12537964", "Name": "Ahmed, Jamshed", "Expires": "2018.10.18" }, 
  { "Class": "C", "Rating": "1535", "ID": "12210580", "Name": "Attaya, James", "Expires": "2019.01.12" }, 
  { "Class": "F", "Rating": "0001", "ID": "16281977", "Name": "Auld, Thomas", "Expires": "1000.10.10" }, 
  { "Class": "B", "Rating": "1793", "ID": "10117780", "Name": "Badamo, Anthony", "Expires": "2018.09.12" }
]
```

JS CODE:

```
let dataString = "Adeyemon, Murie|Ahmed, Jamshed|Attaya, James|Badamo, Anthony|Birmingham, Gerald|"; 
let splitString = dataString.split("|"); 

for (let i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) { 
    $temp = splitString[i - 1]; 
    if ($temp > "") { 
        members.find(x => x.Name === $temp); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you please show an example of the result?

Comment: Why `$temp = splitString[i - 1];` ?

Comment: If I could do that, I would. But at http://verlager.com/super-dev.php I am populating a grid that looks up class and rating. But some of the names don't exist in the members object. I want to list them so the user can cut and paste them accurately into a form. Then the grid can be redrawn.

Comment: @mikey: I have an extra "|" delimiter at the end of the dataString so there is no last token. Hence $temp = splitString[i - 1];

Comment: besides the index error (i -1?) this code `members.find(x => x.Name === $temp);` ... you are finding it, but throwing away the result of `.find`

Comment: but when i == 0, `$temp = splitString[-1]` just use `i` .. and check `$temp.length`

Comment: @verlager you wouldn't have any pipes `|` as you split the original string already by the pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `filter`

```js
var dataString =
  'Adeyemon, Murie|Ahmed, Jamshed|Attaya, James|Badamo, Anthony|Birmingham, Gerald|'
var members = [{"Class":"E","Rating":"1000","ID":"16720664","Name":"Adeyemon, Murie","Expires":"1000.10.10"},{"Class":"B","Rating":"1735","ID":"12537964","Name":"Ahmed, Jamshed","Expires":"2018.10.18"},{"Class":"C","Rating":"1535","ID":"12210580","Name":"Attaya, James","Expires":"2019.01.12"},{"Class":"F","Rating":"0001","ID":"16281977","Name":"Auld, Thomas","Expires":"1000.10.10"},{"Class":"B","Rating":"1793","ID":"10117780","Name":"Badamo, Anthony","Expires":"2018.09.12"}]

var res = dataString.split('|').filter(
  name => !members.map(o => o.Name).find(n => n === name)
).filter(name=>name.trim()!=='')
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Except that the output formatting is ... a little confusing. Please check http://localhost/www/verlager/super-dev.php the output could be Fischer, Robert; Petrosian, Tigran Any chance you could improve this?

Comment: @verlager,I can't open the url you gave ,please use codepen or jsfiddler instead

Comment: I got it to format to my liking. Thanks for your work.

Answer (score 0):

Try [reducing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the `members` array to a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of names. Then you can filter your `splitString` array using [`Set.prototype.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has)

```js
const members = [{"Class":"E","Rating":"1000","ID":"16720664","Name":"Adeyemon, Murie","Expires":"1000.10.10"},{"Class":"B","Rating":"1735","ID":"12537964","Name":"Ahmed, Jamshed","Expires":"2018.10.18"},{"Class":"C","Rating":"1535","ID":"12210580","Name":"Attaya, James","Expires":"2019.01.12"},{"Class":"F","Rating":"0001","ID":"16281977","Name":"Auld, Thomas","Expires":"1000.10.10"},{"Class":"B","Rating":"1793","ID":"10117780","Name":"Badamo, Anthony","Expires":"2018.09.12"}]
const dataString = "Adeyemon, Murie|Ahmed, Jamshed|Attaya, James|Badamo, Anthony|Birmingham, Gerald|";

const names = members.reduce((c, {Name}) => c.add(Name), new Set())
const missing = dataString.split('|')
    .filter(name => name.trim() && !names.has(name))
    .join('; ') // output from your comment on another answer

console.info(missing)
```

I've added in the `name.trim()` to filter out the empty record created by the trailing `|` in your `dataString`.

---

The reason for creating a `Set` is to avoid searching the entire `members` array for each name in `dataString`. `Set.prototype.has()` should be *O(1)*

Answer (score 0):

You can first create `Name` to object mapping and then search name from string in this object/map which will cost O(n) for n names.

```js
var members = [ { "Class": "E", "Rating": "1000", "ID": "16720664", "Name": "Adeyemon, Murie", "Expires": "1000.10.10" }, 
  { "Class": "B", "Rating": "1735", "ID": "12537964", "Name": "Ahmed, Jamshed", "Expires": "2018.10.18" }, 
  { "Class": "C", "Rating": "1535", "ID": "12210580", "Name": "Attaya, James", "Expires": "2019.01.12" }, 
  { "Class": "F", "Rating": "0001", "ID": "16281977", "Name": "Auld, Thomas", "Expires": "1000.10.10" }, 
  { "Class": "B", "Rating": "1793", "ID": "10117780", "Name": "Badamo, Anthony", "Expires": "2018.09.12" }
];

var nameMap = members.reduce((prev, next) => {
  prev[next.Name] = next;
  return prev;
}, {});

let dataString = "Adeyemon, Murie|Ahmed, Jamshed|Attaya, James|Badamo, Anthony|Birmingham, Gerald|"; 
let names = dataString.split("|");

let result = names.filter(name => name && !(name in nameMap));

console.log(result);
```